# python beautifulsoup - pull a list/dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm still leaning how to utilize beautifulsoup. I've managed to use tags and what not to pull the data from Depth Chart table at https://fantasydata.com/nfl-stats/team-details/CHI

But now I'm try to pull the Full Roster table. I can't quite seem to figure out the tags for that. I do notice in the source though that the info is in a list with dictionaries, as seen:

```
vm.Roster = [{"PlayerId":16236,"Name":"Cody Parkey","Team":"CHI","Position":"K","FantasyPosition":"K","Height":"6\u00270\"","Weight":189,"Number":1,"CurrentStatus":"Healthy","CurrentStatusCol

...
```

What's an elegant way to pull that Full Roster table? My thought was if I could just grab that list/dictionary, I could just convert to a dataframe. But not sure how to grab that, or if there is a better way to do that to put that table in a dataframe in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a regular expression to extract the raw JSON object which then can be loaded using the json library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import json

html_page = urlopen("https://fantasydata.com/nfl-stats/team-details/CHI")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
raw_data = re.search(r"vm.Roster = (\[.*\])", soup.text).group(1)
data = json.loads(raw_data)

print(data[0]["Name"])  # Cody Parkey
```

It should be noted that scraping data from that particular site in this fashion most likely violates their terms of service and might even be illegal in some jurisdictions.

Comment: that actually is a good point and hadn't thought of that. I have their paid subscription, so that didn't even cross my mind, i just wanted to practice using beautifulsoup. but thanx for the heads up/awerness

Comment: @chitown88 If you have a subscription there are most likely better ways of getting the data (through API access) than scraping, but then again, it's always fun to use scraping :)

Comment: yes. I use the api for the stuff I need. It is super fast, easy, convenient. but I'm learning so much more with just digging "under the hood" so to speak. and it is fun

Comment: @chitown88 Indeed :)